# DHCP lease time in DrayTek Vigor 2600 Plus

Tags: router, dhcp, adsl

I'm having some problems with my ADSL router DrayTek Vigor 2600 Plus.
After a few days and some people connecting to it, it stops assigning IP addresses to new people that tries to connect.
I was hoping that reducing the DHCP lease time could improve something.

Anyone knows how can I change that in this model?
I was also looking for the user guide on the internet, but couldn't find it anywhere. It would be great if someone points me to the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command

> srv dhcp leasetime [xxx]

You can see it in draytek site:
http://www.draytek.co.uk/support/kb_vigor_dhcpfix.html

Comment: Ok, mine was set to 3 days!!!
I've changed that to 3600 seconds.
Let's see how it does. Thanks.